# Output of composition $\delta_2(\rho_3(1234))$ in $D_4$.

Tags: permutations, symmetric-groups

Have seen a youtube [video](https://youtu.be/8cUiLMqNfHg)
on composition of elements of $D_4$, symmetries of a square.

At 8.33 and before, a composition $\delta_2(\rho_3(1234))$ is given.
The output differs than that obtained by me below.

Request to tell why difference occurs.

$$\delta_2= (1423), \rho_3=(1432)$$
$$\delta_2=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 &4 \\ 4 & 1 & 3 & 2\end{pmatrix} \implies (1423)$$
$$\rho_3=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 &4 \\ 4 & 1 & 2 & 3\end{pmatrix} \implies (1432)$$
First mapping by $\rho_3: (1432)$.
Next, by $\delta_2=(1423)$ as below:
$1_1\to 4_1, 4_2 \to 2_2$
$2_1\to 1_1, 1_2 \to 4_2$
$3_1\to 2_1, 2_2 \to 1_2$
$4_1\to 3_1, 3_2 \to 3_2$

Or,
$(1243)$

But, seems from the video at 8:33, that the output of composition is two disjoint cycles with $1\to 2, 2 \to 1, 3\to4, 4\to 3$, or
$$=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 &4 \\ 2 & 1 & 4 & 3\end{pmatrix}\implies (12)(34)$$

*Edit :*

There is mistake in having one fixed point in $\delta_2$:

$$\delta_2= (1)(42)(3), \rho_3=(1432)$$
$$\delta_2=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 &4 \\ 1 & 4 & 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\rho_3=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 &4 \\ 4 & 1 & 2 & 3\end{pmatrix} \implies (1432)$$
First mapping by $\rho_3: (1432)$.
Next, by $\delta_2=(42)$ as below:
$1_1\to 4_1, 4_2 \to 2_2$
$2_1\to 1_1, 1_2 \to 1_2$
$3_1\to 2_1, 2_2 \to 4_2$
$4_1\to 3_1, 3_2 \to 3_2$

The composition yields correct result now
$$=
\begin{pmatrix} 1_1 & 2_1 & 3_1 &4_1 \\ 2_2 & 1_2 & 4_2 & 3_2 \end{pmatrix}\implies (12)(34)$$

---

Next have correctly given the next (reverse) composition in the video, as below:

$$\delta_2= (1)(42)(3), \rho_3=(1432)$$
$$\delta_2=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 &4 \\ 1 & 4 & 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\rho_3=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 &4 \\ 4 & 1 & 2 & 3\end{pmatrix} $$
$1_1\to 1_1, 1_2 \to 4_2$
$2_1\to 4_1, 4_2 \to 3_2$
$3_1\to 3_1, 3_2 \to 2_2$
$4_1\to 2_1, 2_2 \to 1_2$
$$\rho_3(\delta_2(1234))=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 &4 \\ 4 & 3 & 2 & 1\end{pmatrix} \implies (14)(32)$$

Comment: What you state for $\delta_2$ does not match $(1423)$.  Must be a type as $\delta_2$ cannot have exactly one fixed-point.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts thanks, for pointing out have taken one fixed point, which is not possible here as an object is affected. Either 0, 2 or 4 fixed points should be there. Kindly see the Edit.

Comment: Which answer is "correct" depends on the _convention_  you have established for multiplying two permutations. Some books/videos use left-to-right, some right-to-left.

Comment: @EthanBolker  Based on Cayley table, the natural one would be left to right. I.e. the row element is acted upon first, and the column element the next. Else, right to left is fine - very convenient.